# bash: why can't I copy 3 files into 3 directories that share a name with the files?

Tags: bash, cp, brace-expansion

So if I can do this:

```
$ mkdir ./blah_{007,011,090}
```

And end up with three directories...

Why can't I do this...

```
cp ../blah_{007,011,090}.swf ./blah_{007,011,090}_src
```

And copy the files into 3 directories?

Comment: why should it? `man cp` shows only a single attribute for `DEST` compared to  `SOURCE...` (see the `...`). How should `cp` know when the `SOURCES` end and when the `DEST` begins?

Comment: I more interesting question would be **how** do I copy 3 files into 3 directories that share a name with the files?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor wasn’t that my question?

Comment: No: you asked, what is the reason that the way that I demonstrated does not work (and this is how everyone interpreted it).

Comment: Once could interpret the two brace expansions in your example as *examples* instead of being *accidentally identical*. What if you wanted to copy all `*a*` files into the `007` directory and all `*qqq*` files to the `011` directory? If your use-case is identically-named files, it would be good to put that into your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're effectively running:

```
cp ../blah_007.swf ../blah_011.swf  ../blah_090.swf ./blah_007_src ./blah_011_src ./blah_090_src
```

I trust it is obvious why the above command is not the same as:

```
cp ../blah_007.swf ./blah_007_swc
cp ../blah_011.swf ./blah_011_swc
cp ../blah_090.swf ./blah_090_swc
```

If you want the later, loop over `cp`:

```
for f in blah_{007,011,090}
do
  cp ../"$f.swf" "$f"_swc
done
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to get around writing an entire loop to do that.

Comment: As I don’t have to when I use the mkdir command.

Comment: Can you pass functions in bash?  Cause if you can then I could write a map function.

Comment: Pass functions to? If you want to mv and not cp, you could use `rename` instead.

Answer (score 2):

See `man cp`:

```
   cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
   cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

It shows only a single attribute for `DEST` compared to `SOURCE...` (see the ...). How should `cp` know when the `SOURCES` end and when the `DEST` begins.

Use a `for`-loop.